# EventHandler to Reactive Extensions where event handler is transient lifestyle

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I need to bridge my messaging framework so that when an event occurs (TimeAggregate which contains a members called `Reading` and `Stream`) I can pass into Reactive Extensions and do fancy things:

```
public class TestHandler : ITopicNotificationHandler<TimeAggregate>
{
    public TestHandler(/* singleton variables are injected here */)
    {
    }

    public async Task Handle(TimeAggregate notification, string topic, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // notification contains TimeAggregate.Reading (which is a decimal)
        // and TimeAggregate.Stream (which is a string, i.e. Office1, OfficeA etc)
        // I want to perform an average on TimeAggregate.Reading but split by TimeAggregate.Reading
    }
}
```

How would I go about linking the two (the event handler and Reactive Extension) and splitting so each Reading name is averaged independently (a dictionary of average observable of sorts) per TimeAggregate.Stream key?

***Lifetime details***

Also there is a technical aspect where each time the event handler (`TestHandler`) is called it is build from scratch, the lifetime of TestHandler is transient.

I can get around this by making a static registration manager (which the IoC injects into the TestHandler constructor, or we literally reference as static within).

Comment: Sounds like you want to inject an interface with singleton lifetime, use a `Subject` to capture data and then use `IObservable.Scan` to aggregate variables needed for a running average (total and count) per key. Then you can use `Select` to reduce to the average. Note, your question isn't clear because you describe `TimeAggregate.Reading` as both a string and a decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to inject a service that has singleton lifetime that can be called in the event handler. It can use a `Subject` to generate an observable and expose / utilize an observable of running average messages:

```
public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
{
    private Subject<TimeAggregate> _subject;

    // Calculate tuples of (key, average)
    public IObservable<(string, decimal)> Averages => _subject
        // Group by key
        .GroupBy(s => s.Group)
        .SelectMany(g => g
            .Select(g => g.Reading)
            // Collect element count and running total
            .Scan((elements: 0, total: (decimal)0), (agg, v) => (agg.elements + 1, agg.total + v))
            // Calculate running average
            .Select(t => t.total / t.elements)
            // Associate key and average for SelectMany
            .Select(average => (g.Key, average)));

    public MonitoringService()
    {
        _subject = new Subject<TimeAggregate>();
    }
    public void PostNotification(TimeAggregate notification)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(notification);
    }
}
```

Which can then be used like this:

```cs
var monitoringService = new MonitoringService();
var handler = new TestHandler(monitoringService);

var dict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
monitoringService.Averages.Subscribe<(string group, decimal average)>(t =>
{
    // Do something with running average. In this case populate a dictionary
    dict[t.group] = t.average;
});
```

[image: dictionary of averages]

**Note**: if you want to start calculating averages before an observer is attached, you may want to look into Connectables (`Publish` etc.) and you would want to avoid using a get only generating property like this and instead assign it once in the constructor. But remember that this approach will only push updates to averages, so if a message isn't chatty the average message will be delayed.
e.g.

```cs
public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
{
    private Subject<TimeAggregate> _subject;

    // Calculate tuples of (key, average)
    public IObservable<(string, decimal)> Averages { get; }

    public MonitoringService()
    {
        _subject = new Subject<TimeAggregate>();
        Averages = _subject
        // Group by key
        .GroupBy(s => s.Group)
        .SelectMany(g => g
            .Select(g => g.Reading)
            // Collect element count and running total
            .Scan((elements: 0, total: (decimal)0), (agg, v) => (agg.elements + 1, agg.total + v))
            // Calculate running average
            .Select(t => t.total / t.elements)
            // Associate key and average for SelectMany
            .Select(average => (g.Key, average)))
        .Publish()
        // Connect immediately
        .AutoConnect(0);
    }
    public void PostNotification(TimeAggregate notification)
    {
        _subject.OnNext(notification);
    }
}
```

Full example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main()
        {
            var monitoringService = new MonitoringService();
            var handler = new TestHandler(monitoringService);

            var dict = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
            monitoringService.Averages.Subscribe<(string group, decimal average)>(t =>
            {
                // Do something with running average. In this case populate a dictionary
                dict[t.group] = t.average;
            });

            await handler.Handle(new TimeAggregate
            {
                Group = "Test1",
                Reading = 100
            }, "Test", CancellationToken.None);

            await handler.Handle(new TimeAggregate
            {
                Group = "Test1",
                Reading = 200
            }, "Test", CancellationToken.None);

            await handler.Handle(new TimeAggregate
            {
                Group = "Test2",
                Reading = 200
            }, "Test", CancellationToken.None);

            await handler.Handle(new TimeAggregate
            {
                Group = "Test2",
                Reading = 300
            }, "Test", CancellationToken.None);
        }  
    }

    public class MonitoringService : IMonitoringService
    {
        private Subject<TimeAggregate> _subject;

        // Calculate tuples of (key, average)
        public IObservable<(string, decimal)> Averages => _subject
            // Group by key
            .GroupBy(s => s.Group)
            .SelectMany(g => g
                .Select(g => g.Reading)
                // Collect element count and running total
                .Scan((elements: 0, total: (decimal)0), (agg, v) => (agg.elements + 1, agg.total + v))
                // Calculate running average
                .Select(t => t.total / t.elements)
                // Associate key and average for SelectMany
                .Select(average => (g.Key, average)));

        public MonitoringService()
        {
            _subject = new Subject<TimeAggregate>();
        }
        public void PostNotification(TimeAggregate notification)
        {
            _subject.OnNext(notification);
        }
    }

    public class TestHandler : ITopicNotificationHandler<TimeAggregate>
    {
        private readonly IMonitoringService _monitoringService;

        public TestHandler(IMonitoringService monitoringService)
        {
            _monitoringService = monitoringService;
        }

        public Task Handle(TimeAggregate notification, string topic, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _monitoringService.PostNotification(notification);
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public interface IMonitoringService
    {
        void PostNotification(TimeAggregate notification);
        IObservable<(string group, decimal average)> Averages { get; }
    }

    public class TimeAggregate
    {
        public string Group { get; set; }
        public decimal Reading { get; set; }
    }

    public interface ITopicNotificationHandler<T>
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jason this is fantastic, may have some work if interested can you pop contact details on profile so i can reach out?